# replaceWith(), remove() and empty() don't work

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, replace

I'm using for the first time jQuery (i'm a newbie in Javascript as well) and i created this code for handling form data input:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = $('form :input');

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'process.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'text',
            encode      : true
        }).done(function(data) {
            if (data == "OK") {
                var div = $("#add");
                console.log(div);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

All is ok and i can see the content of div (whose id is `add`) in the console (i'm using code inspector of Chrome).
Now i'm trying to replace the content of the above div with a message to confirm to user that the data has been sent successfully.
I tried to use `.replaceWith()`, `remove()` and `empty()` but none of these works on selected div.

Here is the html form code:

```
<div id="add">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <p>Form fields description</p>
    <hr>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="name">Name:*</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="desc">Surname:*</label>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

What could be the problem? Maybe i'm wrong in something...

**EDIT:**
I tried this:

`$("#add").replaceWith("<h3>New content</h3>");`

and this:

```
var div = $("#add");
div.remove();
```

Comment: Any of those options should work. Can you show what you actually tried? You may just have had a typo.

Comment: Can you  show how you wrote those three functions?

Comment: Just `replaceWith()` would work. No need of using `remove()`

Comment: It works! Maybe i mispelled it. Thank you so much and sorry for my question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try html method of jquery

```
var newContent = "<p>new content<p>"

$("#add").html(newContent);
```